# Consider NA equal in subsetting?

Tags: r, subset

I'm finding that when I am subsetting my dataset I have to use the same pattern consistently, and I'm hoping to simplify this:

```
subset(test, (X1 == 2 | is.na(X1)) & (X2 > 4 | is.na(X2)) )
```

Essentially, I need to consider NA in a column as *also* matching a condition in a subset condition. I'm looking for a function which would produce the same as the above, but ideally, take just the quality conditions and generate the NA condition (or maybe a mode?)

```
na_subset(data, X1 == 2 &  X2 > 4)
```

Some example data:

```
test <- data.frame(
  X1 = c(3L, NA, 7L, NA, 2L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 5L),
  X2 = c(0L, 4L, 5L, 5L, NA, 5L, 8L, 7L, 2L, NA)
)
```

An example query:

```
> subset(test, (X1 == 2 | is.na(X1)) & (X2 > 4 | is.na(X2)) )
  X1 X2
4 NA  5
5  2 NA
```

Comment: Can we see some data?

Comment: That should be &, not &&.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Fixed. Thanks... typing from notes rather than real queries! :)

Comment: Now I'm confused again.  Thet `test` data doesn't contain any 10s or 11s

Comment: Alright -- example and test data are consistent now.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to test this out a bit more but at least for the test you show this works. Here `subsetNA` is the same as `subset.data.frame` except for the one line marked ##:

```
subsetNA <- 
function (x, subset, select, drop = FALSE, ...) 
{
    r <- if (missing(subset)) 
        rep_len(TRUE, nrow(x))
    else {
        e <- substitute(subset)
        r <- eval(e, x, parent.frame())
        if (!is.logical(r)) 
            stop("'subset' must be logical")
        r | is.na(r) ##
    }
    vars <- if (missing(select)) 
        TRUE
    else {
        nl <- as.list(seq_along(x))
        names(nl) <- names(x)
        eval(substitute(select), nl, parent.frame())
    }
    x[r, vars, drop = drop]
}
```

Test it out:

```
> subset(test, (X1 == 2 | is.na(X1)) & (X2 > 4 | is.na(X2)) )
  X1 X2
4 NA  5
5  2 NA
> subsetNA(test, X1 == 2 & X2 > 4)
  X1 X2
4 NA  5
5  2 NA
```

Comment: Thought never occurred to me to just peek at `subset`. I've give this a try, but seems likely the be exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but:

```
data <- data.frame(V1=1:10, V2=c(1:5, NA, 1:4))
subset(data, V1 == 1 &  V2 == 1 | is.na(V1 + V2))
```

Produces:

```
  V1 V2
1  1  1
6  6 NA
```

Comment: That... might actually do it. Need some more thought; Didn't know you could combine the `is.na` arguments like that!

Comment: You are just passing a vector to `is.na`. Functional programming.

Comment: Looks like that's a no go. The `is.na` isn't being distributed through the expression like I was aiming for (get 4 results on test data). Question is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

with `dplyr::if_else()` we can use this pattern:

```r
subset(test, dplyr::if_else(X1 == 2 &  X2 > 4, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
#>   X1 X2
#> 4 NA  5
#> 5  2 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>